# Cinterion MC52i - How to delete ALL SMS?

Tags: sms, modem, at-command

in USB modem (Huawei E1550) command AT+CMGD=0,4 deletes all SMS from memory.

But I cannot do the same in MC52i.
AT+CMGD=? returns just OK, no options it is showing

at+cpms?
+CPMS: "MT",85,85,"MT",85,85,"MT",85,85

How to delete ALL SMS at once?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [ClearLink](http://www.clearconnex.com/content/clearlink) developed by [ClearConnex](http://www.clearconnex.com). ClearLink works on a big list of modules and should be able to help you with your problem. here is the list of other modules:

- Cinterion MC75i
- Cinterion TC63i
- Huawei MG323
- Huawei MU509
- Sierra Wireless Q2687, SL6087, WMP100, Fastrack, GL6100
- Telit GE864-PY